# How do i retrieve data from a protected API via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

this is my first time here so i hope i don't break any rules.

I have a Jquery code that retrieves info from an API that is written from a .net controller. Retrieving the infomration from the API works well, but now that i have to make the user sign in to view the API(Json), it of course stopped working in jquery. Is there anyway i can let the Jquery code "sign in" so it can retrieve data from that API while it's protected with password (authorize)?

Thanks

UPDATE

here is the Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var showData = $('#show-data');

    $.getJSON('url/here', function (data) {
      console.log(data);

      var items = data.map(function (item) {
        return item.id + ': ' + item.firstName + ': ' + item.lastName;
      });

      showData.empty();


        var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
        var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
        showData.append(list);

    });


});
```

Comment: You just need to send the user's authorisation credentials to the API. Generally you'll get a token back from that request which you use to identify the user in subsequent calls. Without knowing the API, or seeing your code, we can't really offer any more help

Comment: I am sorry, please see the updated question above. This is the Jquery code. But  i don't get what you mean by seeing the API, do you want me to post the Controller code or the text(json) returned from the Controller?

Comment: Neither really - we just need to know how you authenticate with the API.

Comment: I authenicate with it by inserting a specific username and password that has a superuser role, that is defined in my Startup.cs file in the .NET server.

Comment: Then you just need to replicate that call via the jQuery code.

Comment: Yes exactly, where should i be looking? I didn't get anything from google as i really don't know what this operation is called.

Comment: I also have a Cookie value to that URL. Would that be any help?